# Jiggling borders in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, layout, frames, pack

Building an interface in tk/tkinter that will consist of numerous frames of various size, all of which will be populated with buttons and labels and text fields (lots of frame.pack() & frame.destroy going on).  I decided to start by populating the root frame with a 6x4 grid and then overlaying that with the temporary frames as needed.  My main goal is to have the frames/labels size out according the user's aspect ratio (adhering to the row/column weights I establish), but then having the borders lock into position once propagated.

Below is a simplified example of what I'm talking about (the colors are just for spacing/clarity):

```
import random


class CharacterInterface:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.display_text = ['']
        self.master = master
        self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.master.title("Interface Template")
        self.master.configure(bg='#000000')

        # generates a 6x4 grid to underpin the interface/keep things spaced out
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(4):
                self.master.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
                self.master.grid_rowconfigure(j, weight=1)
                self.dummy_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, relief=tk.RIDGE, borderwidth=4,
                                            bg='#' + str(2 * j) + str(2 * j) + str(2 * j) + str(i) + str(i) + str(i))
                self.dummy_label = tk.Label(master=self.dummy_frame,
                                            bg='#' + str(i) + str(i) + str(i) + str(2 * j) + str(2 * j) + str(2 * j))
                self.dummy_frame.grid(row=j, column=i, sticky='nsew')
                self.dummy_label.pack(ipadx=8, ipady=8, fill="both", expand=True)

        self.ch_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg='#000077')
        self.ch_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky="nsew")
        self.ch_frame.grid_propagate(False)                     # this locks ch_frame's right border
        self.ch_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.ch_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
        self.ch_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.ch_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=6)
        self.chtop_label = tk.Label(master=self.ch_frame, relief=tk.RIDGE, borderwidth=4, fg="#FFFFFF", bg='#000000',
                                    font=('Courier', 12), justify="left", anchor='nw')
        self.chtop_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.chleft_label = tk.Label(master=self.ch_frame, relief=tk.RIDGE, borderwidth=4, fg="#FFFFFF", bg='#000000',
                                     font=('Courier', 12), justify="left", anchor='nw')
        self.chleft_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.chright_label = tk.Label(master=self.ch_frame, relief=tk.RIDGE, borderwidth=4, fg="#FFFFFF",
                                      bg='#000000', font=('Courier', 12), justify="left", anchor='nw')
        self.chright_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        self.test_button = tk.Button(self.chright_label, text="test", bg='#000000', fg="#FFFFFF",
                                      font=('Courier', 12), relief=tk.FLAT, anchor='w', command=lambda: self.toss())
        self.test_button.pack(side='left')

    def toss(self):
        self.test_button.pack_forget()
        str_length, str_instance = random.randrange(1, 10), ""
        for i in range(str_length):
            str_instance = str_instance + 'a'
        self.chleft_label['text'] = str_instance
        self.test_button.pack(side='left')


root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = CharacterInterface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

So here the 6x4 grid is formed, and the self.ch_frame.grid_propagate(False) setting locks in that right border on ch_frame (the parent frame to the three labels I've created).  But if you click the button it will create a little string in chleft_label and that middle label border starts wiggling around on me.

Is there a way for me to lock that border in place WITHOUT using place() or assigning a width value?  I suppose I could stick a placeholder string in chleft_label, but I would prefer to lock it with propagate commands rather than crummy workarounds (I'm going to be juggling a ton of these frames).  I could also work around it by abandoning the grid format inside ch_frame, but then I'm losing some of the core functionality I want (only updating the frames/labels as needed).

Is this a dead end, trying to assert this sort of border positioning in a grid/pack interface?

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering: what system do you have (Mac, Windows, Linux)? I ran your code, and nothing jiggled. I'm on a Linux (Ubuntu, specifically).

Comment: Thanks for running it.

I've got it going on two machines (Windows 10 and Windows 7) and the jiggling occurs in both cases.  If you press the button repeatedly the position of the border between chleft_label and chright_label shifts around depending on the length of the test string in chleft_label.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I misunderstood what jiggling meant. Yes, it actually _does_ do  that when I run it. Will look into it...

Comment: I'm currently not on a machine to test it but I guess you get around with `padx`. Could you provide a image of your issue for me?

Comment: Don't think padx will do it. Lines 28-29 above I've got columns at 1:3 (so chleft_label is 1/3rd the width of chright_label). Problem is the grid inside of ch_frame reads this ratio as a suggestion rather than a parameter and will modify the width when you start adding widgets.

I was having the same issue with ch_frame but was able to lock it with the grid_propagate(false) command at line 27. I thought this would apply the child grids contained within ch_frame as well, but it doesn't. In fact it seems that command doesn't apply to the grid contained in ch_frame.

Comment: Did you try setting the width option when creating `self.chleft_label`?

Comment: Sure, although like I said my goal is to really force the labels to adhere to the grid_columnconfigure() value I'm setting (1:3 in this case) rather than hard coding a width (since I want it to auto-adjust based on the user's resolution).  But in this case even when you assign a width to self.chleft_label you get a small amount of movement when you first hit the 'test' button.  That stuff drives me crazy.

There MUST be a way to do this with weighted ratios and grid_propagate(), right?  Otherwise what good is the grid system in tkinter?

Comment: Try adding `uniform=1` in the two `self.ch_frame.grid_columnconfigure(...)`.  BTW I don't get any *jiggling* when I set `width=10` when creating `self.chleft_label`.

Comment: Now THAT looks like a solution.  What the heck is uniform=1 doing?

Comment: "The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their -weight values" ~ ugh, how did I miss that in the documentation. Thank you ACW1668, that's precisely the fix I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@acw1668 nailed it - I just needed to add a `uniform=1` parameter to my `self.ch_frame.grid_columnconfigure()`s. The definition was staring right at me in the documentation:

*"The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their -weight values"*

Comment: Be sure to accept your answer, so that other users know that the question has been satisfactorily answered. Glad you finally figured it out! :-)